# Design de accesso à base de dados MySql

Tags: php, mysql, design-pattern

Eu ando a investigar implementações boas e que permitam uma facil adaptabilidade para conecção à minha db. Gostava de receber *feed backs* e sugestões acerca de melhorias a este design. Como por exemplo: como implementaria neste modelo mais do que uma base de dados, será que seria melhor usar uma classe abstrata para a base de dados, se sim, como o faria? Estou num projeto que tem várias fases, futuramente poderá haver necessidade de alteração/acrescento de DB's e tabelas e não gostaria de ter quase de refazer a estrutura. Conteudo dos ficheiros:

config.php:

```
$db1Config = array(
   "dbName" => "master_db",
   "dbUser" => "master_user",
   "dbPassword" => "master_pass",
   "dbHost" => "master_host"
);
```

Class DB, DB.php:

```
class DB {

   private static $_instance = Null;
   private $_db = Null;

   public function __construct($dbConfig) {

      try {
         $this->_db = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$dbConfig["dbHost"]. ';dbname=' .$dbConfig["dbName"], $dbConfig["dbUser"], $dbConfig["dbPassword"]);
        $this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        //echo $error;
        echo 'Updating database. Try again in a few moments. Sorry';
        die();
      }
   }

   public static function getInstance($dbConfig) {
      if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
         self::$_instance = new DB($dbConfig);
      }
      return self::$_instance;
   }

   public function select_data($table, $where, $column, $upOrDown)
      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

Class Service, Service.php

```
class Service {

   private $_db = Null;

   public function __construct($dbConfig) {
      $this->_db = DB::getInstance($dbConfig);
   }

   public function service_exists($servId) {
      $servExists = $this->_db->select_data('services', array('id', '=', $servId), Null, Null);

      if (count($servExists) > 0) {
         return True;
      }

      return False;
   ...
}
```

index.php

```
$service = new Service($db1Config);
if($service->service_exists($servId) {
   ...
}
...
```

Comment: o que é no seu entendimento "escaláveis para conecção à minha db"

Comment: Poder usar este design caso haja mais implementações a fazer, outras conecções, outra DB, etc...

Comment: então edite a sua pergunta e altere a palavra para adaptabilidade pois um sistema escalável em base de dados é aquele que permite crescer em numero de base de dados ou tabelas de forma a responder em numero de acessos.

Comment: Editada, desculpe o mal entendido

Comment: não precisa de pedir desculpa apenas achei que para obter uma boa resposta você precisa de ser preciso e não deixar a dúvida em quem o pode ajudar.

Comment: Miguel, poderia dar um exemplo, a pergunta parece muito abrangente e ou baseada em opiniões, correndo o risco de ser fechada. Edite-a adicionando exemplos e situações onde seu código não se adeque.

Answer (score 1):

Ao analisar a sua implementação, não vejo nada de mal.

Quanto à sua adaptabilidade em vários casos percebo o que tenta fazer tendo um **array de configuração base**.

É comum observar em implementações configurações em ficheiros `PHP`, e até com a presença de variáveis `GLOBAIS`. No entanto tenho encontrado situações em que administradores de sistema não percebem de `PHP` e nesse sentido e apesar de não ser difícil, hoje enquanto programador profissional entendo que devemos utilizar alguns standards.

Seja para o futuro, seja para passarmos formas organizadas quanto à configuração de um sistema por nós criado. Hoje estamos por dentro do que fazemos mas amanhã já não nos lembramos. É ainda importante para os projectos que produzimos que amanhã outros possam mexer com o mesmo na nossa ausência.

Assim e para a configuração ao invés de um array em código php... porque não utilizar  por exemplo um ficheiro INI.

Utilizador da base de dados, sua passsword, etc... são configurações que podem ser alteradas com alguma frequência e não deveria ser necessário entender `PHP` para poder modificar esse tipo de configuração.

Quanto à sua lógica de classes não vejo nada demais mas para o ajudar mais você tem de ser mais concreto.